# Scratched CD-ROM / Sector by sector reading / SCSI command

Tags: data-recovery, scsi, cd-rom

I'm trying to recover data from a slightly scratched CD-ROM.

I've tested without success various free or proprietary software (the recover process couldn't even start). I tried to figure out what happened and so far and I've discovered that the size of the CD-ROM was 0. SCSI command `READ CD CAPACITY` returns 0 Logical Block Addresses / LBA. The CD is not empty, and was not formatted for info.

Consequently all reading access via `READ CD` SCSI command raise exceptions because asked LBA are *out of range*.

I also tried SCSI command : `READ CD MSF` command in order to address directly the physical addresses without considering the logical addresses.  Unsuccessfully, it raises the same error *out of range* error based on LBA ?)

Any idea or help is welcome !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might get a better response on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Consider trying other CD-ROM drives, if you have access to them.  Since it's a problem in the physical layer, that may be the easiest way to work around it!